# Convert query a query builder

Tags: laravel

Possible query a laravel query builder,lo que trato de hacer son las operaciones para calcular el descuto salarial de un dia faltado y si cuenta con prestamo tambien descontarlo

```
select empleado.sueldo_inci,empleado.sal_diario,
((empleado.sueldo_inci-empleado.sal_diario)-Prestamo.descuento) 
as final,Prestamo.descuento from empleado
inner join Prestamo on empleado.idemp=1
```

Comment: Greetings! This is a main, english-speeking version of the StackOverflow. Consider using https://es.stackoverflow.com/ for your question.
Saludos! Esta es la versión en inglés del sitio.Intenta preguntar en inglés o usa otra versión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\DB::table('empleado')
->join('prestamo', 'empleado.id', 'prestado.empleado_id')
->select(['empleado.sueldo_inci', 'empleado.sal_diario', 'prestamo.descuento'])
->selectRaw('(empleado.sueldo_inci - empleado.sal_diario - prestamo.descuento) AS final')
->get()
```